# Calculate number of hours between two string timestamp python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp

how can i calculate number of hours between two timestamp has the following formate:

'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p' as string in my dataframe

how can i do it using python??

Example :

start time:
2016-04-12 20:57:00 PM

end time:
 2016-04-13 06:16:00 AM

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research? You haven't even provided example input and output.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
diff= (pd.to_datetime(end,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p') -
       pd.to_datetime(start,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p'))
hours = diff.total_seconds()//3600 # // rounds down
print(hours)
#9.0
#diff.total_seconds()/3600
#9.316666666666666
```